# Signing transaction clerification

Tags: cleos, keosd

I am trying to understand tx signing in a simplest form.
I am running a local node.

1. Creating wallet is mandetory to store the keys?
2. Wallet is must to create an account?

Transaction Signing

1. Is there any way using cleos/rest api to sign a transaction by passing private key?
   I mean i do not want to use keosd/wallet to sign my transaction offline

Answer (score 1):

### tx signing:

1. Yes.  You must use keosd.
2. Yes.

So I can better understand your approach, what are you trying to do?  I cannot envision a scenario in which you wouldn't want to use keosd unless you're using eosjs in which case you could store and sign with keys in a .env file.

1. keosd is what is used natively to sign the transactions in the request and response process to produce a transaction.

See the tutorial: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/wallets